# Checkbox alignment inside div

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I want to put checkbox inside a div tag. I want to create like [image: this output]

but the result that I get was like [image: this]

the checkbox position should be at the right.

Comment: Share you code.

Comment: Easiest way: create a table with three columns. First column: pic, second: text, third: checkbox. Vertical align the content to middle. And anyway [google](https://www.google.ie/search?q=css+side+by+side+elements) how to put elements side by side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a containing div, then add three floating divs, one per element; Media element, text element, then check box. clear your float within the containing div. Place the check box in the far left div. Adjust CSS as needed.

Here is a working fiddle [Check out the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7wo01ck5/3/)

```
#media_cont {
  height:200px;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #000;
  border-radius:10px;
  padding:5px;
}
.media_content {
  float:left; 
  width:33%;
  text-align:center;
}

#checkbox {
  margin-top:15%;
 }
.clear {
  clear:both;
}
.container {
  padding-top:10px;
}
<div id="media_cont">
    <div class="media_content"><img src="#" width="200" height="200"></div>
    <div class="media_content">
        <div>
            <h2 class="header">
                John Doe
            </h2>
            <h4 class="header">
                User Profile 1
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>   
    <div id="checkbox" class="media_content"><input type="checkbox" checked></div> 
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <p>
            New section
        </p>
    </div>

    </div>
```

**UPDATE**: If you wish to have the check box clicked, simply add some JQuery such as the following:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#profile").click(function() {
       $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr("checked", "checked");
    });
});
```

Then add the call id `profile` to your containing divs class.

```
<div id="profile" class="profile">
```

Here is an updated fiddle:
[Click inside div and append checked into input field](https://jsfiddle.net/7wo01ck5/12/)

Comment: how to make the checkbox checked when user just click in the media_cont area?

Comment: @user3103783 see update to answer along with updated fiddle using jQuery.

Comment: @user3103783 glad this helped out!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
.myDiv{
    position: relative;
}

.myCheckbox {
    position: absolute:
    top: 50px; /* you compute this properly */
    right: 15px; /* you compute this properly */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use awesome bootstrap checkbox
http://flatlogic.github.io/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox/demo/